# How can I make a newline between the rows in JSON?

Tags: php, json

I would like to make a newline between the rows in JSON.

```
foreach($row as $rec){
        $json_array['-code'] = $rec['code'];
        $json_array['ename'] = $rec['ename'];
        $json_array['cname'] = $rec['cname'];
        array_push($json_data,$json_array);

    }
    echo json_encode($json_data);
```

How can I make it to...

```
{"-code":"01",
 "ename":"myname",
 "cname":"myname",
```

...and so on

Comment: what? why? do you want `json_encode($json_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`?

Comment: json encode may strip them, but if not  `$json_array['-code'] = $rec['code']."\n";`

Comment: @Dagon this newline will change the value and in json it'll be anyway `\n` not a newline character

Comment: fair enough @lupatus

Answer (score 0):

since PHP5.4 you can add JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

```
echo json_encode($json_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```